# Does PythonMagick module exist anymore?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pycharm

We are writing a python program that will be converting a word(.doc) to text format. All the modules that we are using are dependent on the PythonMajick module.

I am using Pycharm and I am unable to find the module in both Python 3.6 and Python 2.7.

My question is:
1) Does pythonmagick module exist anymore?
2) If not, how did you get around it. The end goal is to convert a doc file into a text file in python

Comment: _I am unable to find the module in both Python 3.6 and Python 2.7_ Where did you look?  It's a third-party library, so you would have to install it yourself.

Comment: Thank you John! Coming from Java world, can you let me know if I am thinking in the right direction. Do I have to install it on my machine and then import it to PyCharm?

Comment: You have to install it, and assuming you did it right, PyCharm should automatically see it.